# it not sending text to website using webrequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, send, httpwebresponse

I want to programatically send data to a website and then programatically click submit button. This is the HTML code I'm trying to fill up:

```
<textarea id="rpslBox:postRpsl:rpslObject" name="rpslBox:postRpsl:rpslObject" class="ripe-input-field ui-corner-all" rows="18" style="width:500px;"></textarea>
```

I'm using this C# code:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://apps.db.ripe.net/syncupdates/simple-rpsl.html ");
 // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
 request.Method = "POST";
 string textarea = "text";

 // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
 string postData = string.Format("rpslBox:postRpsl:rpslObject{0}", textarea);
```

When I run this code it returns the HTML code of the page without sending this text. How can I send this text? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there also any code you have tried to set the content of the textarea? Doesn't this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explain what you should do?

Comment: actually i dont get that how to click submit buton .  request.Method = "POST"; is enough ?

Comment: Did you try the example on the page?

Comment: And no  `request.Method = "POST";` will not submit your data, but it means that when you send your form, POST should be used as the method of sending (i.e. `<form method="POST">` and `<form method="GET">`!)

Comment: i tried example i think my problem is that i dont know how to submit

Answer (score 0):

I can't test if this works, but from what I understand from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), is that following code will convert your postdata to bytedata and submit that to the webserver:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close ();
```

And that afterwards following code can be used to read the new response from the webserver:

```
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

Comment: for example if i want to login facebook it stayed at login page because i couldnt click submit .

Comment: My guess is that you have to follow the rules from the http protcol like this [page](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod) explains. What happens if you try to set something like `home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies` in you postData?